# is there a function that edits a specific line in a text file vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I am trying to edit a line in a text file knowing that the file contains thousands of line.
Can any body help please ?
i have tried this one but in vain

```
Dim file As New StreamWriter("prds.dt")
file.write("text")
  file.close
```

Comment: Are you identifying this line by number or content?

Comment: No there is not. You have no choice but to read and write the file, but there are various ways to do that. Put some thought into how you would do it, do it and then, if that doesn't work, show us what you did and tell us what happened. We may be able to help with that problem.

Comment: To clarify, you can only overwrite part of a file if you know exactly where to write and you do so with the same number of bytes. For a text file, you'd have to be using fixed-length lines and an encoding where every character is represented by the same number of bytes. That would be unusual. Generally speaking, you would just read and write all the prior lines, read and modify and write the line of interest, then read and write the remaining lines. If you have to write to a new file and then replace the old when you're done, so be it.

Comment: i am trying to store data in text file and modifie some chars in it when needed, to not use much memory i am  trying to replace the only chars of interest, but it looks like even if there are 100000 lines it doesnt eat mutch so i used the one you said read all lines replace the characters and then replace everything in the old file thank you for your help .

Answer (score 1):

How to change line X of a file:

```vb
    Imports System.IO

    ...
    Private Sub ChangeLine(ByVal path as String, ByVal lineNumber as Integer, ByVal newContent As String

       Dim lines() as String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
       lines(lineNumber - 1) = newContent 'arrays run from 0; line X of the file is in array slot X - 1
       File.WriteAllLines(path, lines) 'simple version, or choose a version that uses particular encoding

     End Sub
```

Note there is no checking here; if the file doesn't have at least the number of lines, you get a crash. Robusting this up is a task for the user of this code

How to change all lines that say X, so they say Y, of a file:

```vb
    Imports System.IO

    ...
    Private Sub FindReplaceInFile(ByVal path as String, ByVal findString as String, ByVal replaceWith As String

       Dim lines() as String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
       For i as Integer = 0 to lines.Length - 1
           lines(i) = lines(i).Replace(findStr, replaceWith) 'case sensitive!
       Next i
       File.WriteAllLines(path, lines) 'simple version, or choose a version that uses particular encoding

     End Sub
```